# Java string set default value if null

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

Is there a proficient way to set a string to some default value if assignment gives nullPointerException?

Say im initializing a string like this:

```
String myString= jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("myString").getAsString();
```

If it gives nullPointer i need to give it a default value, i know i can do it with an "if" check after but is that the only way? It would mean alot of checks as i am initiating around 20 strings.

Is there any way to do it like:

```
String myString = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("myString")
    .getAsString() || "defaultValue";
```

Comment: *"as i am initiating around 20 strings"* ... when you what to get JSON data into variable, then you should use a proper JSON parser like Jackson or gson, instead of doing that yourself.

Comment: What's the return type of `getAsJsonObject()`?

Comment: @steffen The return type of `getAsJsonObject()` is a JsonObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about make a method to do that.

```
String getOrDefault(JsonElement jsonElement, String key)
    JsonObject obj = jsoneElement.getAsJsonObject().get(key);
    return obj==null?"default":obj.getAsString();
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good way to do it, and in my case i will have the same default value for all strings.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Optional` for that, as in:

```
Optional.of(jsonElement).map(element -> element.getAsJsonObject()).map(o -> o.get("myString")).map(e -> e.getAsString()).orElse("defaultValue");
```

Comment: Put all the cases in an array. Loop over the array calling this with the elements of the array in the "myString" part.